# How to alert user with local notifications when the value in label is under threshold in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I'm trying to alert the user with local notification when randomly generated integer value is more than the label's text value in Swift 4. I have looked for answers in Google even though I implemented them to my problem as required I couldn't solve it. Here is my code:

```swift
    import UIKit
    import Dispatch
    import QuartzCore
    import UserNotifications


    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var alertButton: UIButton {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 150, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: 100))
            button.setTitle("Show Alert", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAlert), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }

        var valueLabel: UILabel {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 300, width: 150, height: 150))
            label.text = "Value"
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            return label
        }

        var value: Int = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.view.addSubview(alertButton)
            self.view.addSubview(valueLabel)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            requestSettings()

            //let link = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateLabels))
            //link.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateLabels), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        private func requestAuthorization(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> ()) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge]) { (success, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Auth request failed. \(error) \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                completionHandler(success)
            }
        }

        private func requestSettings() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (notificationSettings) in
                switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
                    case .notDetermined:
                        self.requestAuthorization { (success) in
                            guard success else { return }
                            self.scheduleNotification()
                    }
                    case .denied:
                        print("App not allowed to display notification")
                    case .authorized:
                        self.scheduleNotification()
                    case .provisional:
                        self.scheduleNotification()
                }
            }
        }

        @objc func updateLabels() {
            self.value = Int.random(in: 1...50)
            print("\(self.value)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.valueLabel.text = "\(self.value)"
            }
        }

        @objc func showAlert() {
            var val: String = ""
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Threshold", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "Enter an integer value:"
            })
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                val = (alert.textFields?.first!.text)!
                if self.value > Int(val)! {
                    self.scheduleNotification()
                }
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        private func scheduleNotification() {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

            content.title = "App"
            content.subtitle = "WARNING!"
            content.body = "Threshold value is passed"

            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification_id", content: content, trigger: trigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error) \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
        {
            completionHandler([.alert])
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update: I tried implementing local push notification. But my problem is that i can't push it to the user depending on the condition i mentioned.

Comment: where is your local notification code? and what exactly is not working?

Comment: That's the part i couldn't implement. At first, i tried printing a warning to console to see if it is working correctly. It did but when i couldn't implement local push notification after that.

Comment: what does it mean you couldn't? What is exactly the problem? did you try?

Comment: Yes i tried it several times but it didn't work and i didn't want to keep a non-working code in my project so i erased it. That's why local notification part is not there.

Comment: So how I can help you if you don't want to show what is not working?

Comment: 1. Your timer changes the local value every second, but the alert with text field is triggered on button press. Not sure how these two are supposed to work together. 2. Where is the code to extract value from the text field, and compare it with the randomly generated integer?

Comment: Also, please don't name your variable `value`, and it's label `valueLabel` (even if its a temporary code).